# Can we use Cell Range Validation to populate a dropdown list in excel from another sheet in EPPLUS

Tags: excel, .net-core, epplus, libreoffice-calc

I am new to using EPplus. I actually wanted to populate a dropdown list in **Sheet1** from a list of values in **Sheet2**. This can be achieved by Cell Range Validation in Excel.But I am not sure whether EPPlus support this programmatically. It will be really helpful if anyone could help me out.
[Populate a dropdown in this Designation Column from Designation Column in Sheet 2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4ncu.png)
[Sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/js67O.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be great, you post a Minimum Working Example, so people can have better idea of what your question was.

Comment: Thanks @Amir,I have posted images to explain in detail what my query was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it:

```
var departmentSheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("department");
departmentSheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "Management";
departmentSheet.Cells["A2"].Value = "Administrator";
departmentSheet.Cells["A3"].Value = "Quality Engineering";
departmentSheet.Cells["A4"].Value = "Enablers";

var designationSheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("designations");
designationSheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "Developer 1";
designationSheet.Cells["A2"].Value = "Developer 2";
designationSheet.Cells["A3"].Value = "Developer 3";
designationSheet.Cells["A4"].Value = "Developer 4";

// add a validation and set values
// the range of cells that will contain the validation
var validation = departmentSheet.DataValidations.AddListValidation("B1:B4");

// set validation rules as required
validation.ShowErrorMessage = true;
validation.ErrorStyle = ExcelDataValidationWarningStyle.warning;
validation.ErrorTitle = "An invalid value was entered";
validation.Error = "Select a value from the list";

// set the range that contains the validation list
validation.Formula.ExcelFormula = $"={ designationSheet.Name }!$A$1:$A$4";
```